# Azure DevOps Release can't find package

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm having trouble with configuring Azure DevOps Releases to push an ASP.NET service to an on premise server.

My pipeline yaml looks like:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Dev'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: echo 'building $(solution) to $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: echo 'publishing CameraService from $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    artifactName: 'CameraService'
```

The pipeline builds successfully but I'm not quite understanding where the package/artifact is being placed. Several tutorials seem to indicate there's a link from the job but I don't see it in the devOps UI.

On my release the IIS Web App Deploy task fails with:

```
No package found with specified pattern.<br/>Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job.
```

The Package or Folder setting I'm using is

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\*.zip
```

I don't see any place I can view the artifacts to confirm it's matching the path defined in the Release. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

*Edit: Adding yaml from the 2 tasks in stage by request:

IIS Web App Manage

```
steps:
- task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'IIS Web App Manage'
  inputs:
    IISDeploymentType: '$(Parameters.IISDeploymentType)'
    WebsiteName: '$(Parameters.WebsiteName)'
    AddBinding: '$(Parameters.AddBinding)'
    Bindings: '$(Parameters.Bindings)'
    ParentWebsiteNameForVD: '$(Parameters.WebsiteName)'
    VirtualPathForVD: '$(Parameters.VirtualPathForApplication)'
    ParentWebsiteNameForApplication: '$(Parameters.WebsiteName)'
    VirtualPathForApplication: '$(Parameters.VirtualPathForApplication)'
    PhysicalPathForApplication: '%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot\[*removed for security even tho it's proably ok*]'
    AppPoolName: '$(Parameters.AppPoolName)'
```

IIS Web App Deploy

```
steps:
- task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'IIS Web App Deploy'
  inputs:
    WebSiteName: '$(Parameters.WebsiteName)'
    TakeAppOfflineFlag: True
    XmlVariableSubstitution: True
```

Comment: Show the full YAML for your release. If you're using a separate pipeline for deployment, you have to tell that pipeline where to retrieve the build artifacts from.

Comment: @DanielMann Thanks Daniel, I've updated the question with the yaml I can find from the devOps UI, hope that helps.

Comment: Is your release stage defined in a yaml file or is it a classic release (ie defined in the Azure DevOps GUI)?  If it is a classic release have you added any build artifacts?

Comment: @NickGraham I'm new to devOps automation so I'm going to guess it's classic since I went through the GUI. I don't see a way to get to the stage definition but I'll google it. Thanks for the lead!

Comment: this should give you a good starting point - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't see any place I can view the artifacts to confirm it's
> matching the path defined in the Release.

You can follow my steps to locate the cause of the issue and resolve it.

**For Build pipeline side:**

1.Check log of the `PublishBuildArtifact` task and make sure it do upload files.

[image]

2.Navigate to pipeline run page and download the uploaded package to check:

[image]

**For Classic Release pipeline(GUI) side:**

1.Normally we set the build pipeline run as artifact source:

[image]

[image]

After setting the build pipeline run as artifact source, the release will automatically download the outputs from build pipeline.

2.For IIS Web App Deploy task, you can use this button to view its content.

[image]

Check if the Build Artifact from Build pipeline do produces a `xx.zip` file.

[image]

**Note:**

We need to add the build pipeline as artifact source of release pipeline(recommended), or add a `download artifact task` in agent job so that our release can access the build artifacts.